# Поиск по базе данных Python Telebot(pyTelegramBotAPI)

Tags: python, mysql, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Имеется следующий КОД

```py
@bot.message_handler(commands=['search'])
def search_message(message):
    sch = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Enter parameter(author, year, name)')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(sch, process_search_step)


def process_search_step(message):
    sql = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE Name_of_the_book = %s"
    query = message.text
    cursor.execute(sql, (query,))
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    for x in result:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, x)
```

Боту отправляется сообщение с каким-то параметром (автор, год, издательство или название книги), в ответ должны получать ряд строк с данными, но бот отправляет только одну строку

Например

Ввожу название книги бот должен выдать АВТОРА, ГОД, ИЗДАТЕЛЬСТВО, НАЗВАНИЕ КНИГИ и тд.

Но получаю только АВТОРА КНИГИ.

Answer (score 1):

бд для примера:

> author = лев, year = 1600, izd = село, name book = война и мир

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM info WHERE author=?"
cursor.execute(sql, [("лев")])

>>> [('лев', '1600', 'село', 'война и мир')]
```